# How can authors choose a different display name?

Tags: 7, theming

I am looking to add to the create user feature to allow or display a drop down and or a text field that would allow the user to create a custom display name to associate with the post he or she would be creating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this doesn't allow for someone to choose their name per post, it does allow for someone to have a username and a "realname" http://drupal.org/project/realname

You could also just add a text field to nodes where they can fill out any name they want. Then plug that field into your theme instead of the username.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any module etc. that would create this functionality.

This doesn't mean that it can't be done.

One way of doing this, would be to add a field on nodes, where the user could enter the author name. If present, you could then change the default author name with the value entered by the user.